# Questions about the Content-Type header in REST requests and responses

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

I'm new to REST applications and I have several questions regarding the `Content-Type` header.

Suppose I make a request to `GET /my-app/resources` and I want both the request and response body to be in JSON. So theoretically the `Content-Type` should be `application/json`.

The questions I have are the following:

1. Does the `Content-Type` header in the request specify the content type of the request body or the desired content type of the response body?
2. Supposing the `Content-Type` header specifies the content type of the request body, is there another header to specify the desired content type of the response body?
3. Will the response to my request have a `Content-Type` header or another header to specify the content type of its body (response body)?

Please answer with an example. Thanks.

Comment: `Content-Type` only applies to the request **body** - so for a `GET` which doesn't have any request body, it's not needed. To define what you want back, use the `Accept` header - and define `application/json` (or whatever else you can and want to accept)

Comment: @marc_s, so if the resquest was a POST I would use Content-Type for the request body and Accept for the desired response body, is that right? Also, will the response have a header with the content type of the response body?

Comment: Yes, exactly right - and yes, the HTTP response also has a collection of headers. Check out a tool like Postman (www.getpostman.com) or similar to allow you to post queries like this, and see all that's going on over the wire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Does the Content-Type header in the request specify the content type of the request body or the desired content type of the response body?

Answer -> Content-Type header in the request specify the content type of the request body only

> 2. Supposing the Content-Type header specifies the content type of the request body, is there another header to specify the desired content type of the response body?

Answer -> you have to use:

```
Accept: <MIME_type>/<MIME_subtype> | <MIME_type>/* | */*
```

to specify the desired content type of the response body

> 3. Will the response to my request have a Content-Type header or another header to specify the content type of its body (response body)?

Answer -> Content-Type: Indicates the media type (e.g. `text/html` or `application/json`) of the response sent to the client by the server, this will help the client in processing the response body correctly.

Comment: I don’t think the answer to part 3 is correct. They are asking about the response.

Comment: Yes barry you are right, my mistake, below is the correct answer of 3rd question
 Content-Type:  Indicates the media type (text/html or text/JSON) of the response sent to the client by the server, this will help the client in processing the response body correctly.

Comment: Agreed. Can you edit your answer then to show that?